# How to remove unnecessary items from an JSON with JQ?

Tags: json, jq, object-slicing

I need from this: (example)

```
{
  "jobs": [
      {},
      {}
    ],
  "services": {
    "service-1": {
      "version": "master"
    },
    "service-2": {
      "foo": true,
      "version": "master"
    },
    "service-3": {
      "bar": "baz"
    }
  }
}
```

Make this:

```
{
  "services": {
    "service-1": {
      "version": "master"
    },
    "service-2": {
      "version": "master"
    }
  }
}
```

So delete all except `.services.*.version`. Help please, can't handle it with my knowledge of the JQ.

Comment: Rather than thinking of it as __removing__ unwanted values... think of it as __selecting__ wanted values instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating your expression `.services.*.version` quite generically, you could use `tostream` as follows:

```
reduce (tostream
        | select(length==2 and
                 (.[0] | (.[0] == "services" and
                          .[-1] == "version")))) as $pv (null;
    setpath($pv[0]; $pv[1]) )
```

### Using jq's streaming parser

To reduce memory requirements, you could modify the above solution to use jq's streaming parser, either with `reduce` as above, or with `fromstream`:

```
jq -n --stream -f program.jq input.json
```

where program.jq contains:

```
fromstream(inputs
    | select( if length == 2
              then .[0] | (.[0] == "services" and
                           .[-1] == "version")
              else . end ) )
```

#### `.services.*.version.*`

Interpreting `.services.*.version` more broadly so as not to require the terminal component of the path to be `.version`, simply replace
`.[-1] == "version"`
with:

```
index("version")
```

in the above.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to differentiate between "version" being absent or null:

```
{services}
| .services |= map_values(select(has("version")) | {version} )
```